# mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

Tags: php, sql, mysql, warnings, mysql-num-rows

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result))
{
echo "no match found!";
}
```

it is throwing an error-

`Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in D:\Hosting\6448289\html\includes\getQuestion.php on line 72`

Comment: It is the error of mysql_query(), Please check this or check select query also....

Comment: LOL no, the code *after* this line is not needed :) Although no need to show any code. the problem is clear. You have an error while query execution. Use codaddict's code to see what error you experience.

Answer (score 5):

You need to check the return value of [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

```
$query = 'YOUR QUERY';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    trigger_error('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error()." in ".$query);
}
// go ahead and fetch the results using mysql_num_rows.
```

If `mysql_query` fails it returns `boolean` `false` instead of a `resource`.

When you pass this `boolean` value to `mysql_num_rows` you get this error.

Comment: A more concise version is `mysql_query(...) or trigger_error(mysql_error())`

Comment: edited code to be more useful and reliable