# Password Changer [Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource]

Tags: php, mysql-num-rows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698740/mysql-num-rows-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource)

I am using simple self-created php script to change password to my wow server's website.
Here's the error:

> "Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects
>   parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in D:\wamp\www\password.php on
>   line 24"

Password script:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){  
 change_db($realm_DB);  
 $loginusername = "$acc_name";  
 $loginpass = $_POST['password'];  
 $sha_pass_hash = sha1(strtoupper($loginusername) . ":" . strtoupper($loginpass));  
 $qry=mysql_query("UPDATE `$realm_DB`.`account` SET `sha_pass_hash`='$sha_pass_hash', `v`='', `s`='', WHERE (`username`='$loginusername');");  
 if (mysql_num_rows($qry) == 1){  
?>  
  < script type="text/javascript" >  
  {  
   alert("Successfully changed password!");  
  }  
  < /script>  
< ?php  
}  
}  
?>
```

I added spaces to script type javascript and php tag just because you could see it.
Anyway I added "or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql)" after "$qry" to see the sql error.
Here it is:

> "Notice: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE (`username`='ADMIN')' at
>   line 1 in D:\wamp\www\password.php on
>   line 23"

I don't know what causes those errors because I can register and login to my site.
Gief a help!

Answer (score 2):

In your SQL you have a `,` before your `WHERE` clause which is invalid.

Also, `mysql_query`  will return `true` or `false` for an `UPDATE` query not a resource. You should use `mysql_affected_rows` to ensure the row was updated *not* `mysql_num_rows`.

Check the [documentation for `mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query)

Answer (score 1):

From looking at it quickly, you have a comma that shouldn't be there just before the WHERE keyword:

```
s='' , WHERE
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that your query is throwing an error (ie you have an invalid SQL string), and therefore the $qry variable is containing FALSE instead of the result object you expect.

You should check for this first. If it is FALSE, you can then use `mysql_error()` to find what the error actually was. This will help you debug your SQL string.

Comment: Thanks guys! SQL error is fixed but is the warning fixable or removeable?