# PHP mysql_num_rows() Returns error

Tags: php, mysql, html, error-log, mysql-num-rows

I have a PHP login script. This is the part where the person can create a new user. My issue is I want to check if the user exists, and if the username does not exist the the table, than create the new user. However, if the user does exist, I want it to return an error in a session variable. Here is the code I have right now. This doesn't include my DB connections, but I know they do work. Its `num_rows()` that is being written as an error in the error_log file. Here is the code:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username';";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0) //user exists
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    $_SESSION['reg_error']='User already exists';
    die();
}
else
{
$query = "INSERT INTO users ( username, password, salt )
        VALUES ( '$username' , '$hash' , '$salt' );";
mysql_query($query);
mysql_close();
header('Location: index.php');
```

The error it is giving me is

```
mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in [dirctory name]
```

Comment: To check whether a row exist or not, you can use SELECT COUNT(*)

Comment: You need to do error checking on `mysql_query()`.  `if (!$result) echo mysql_error()`

Comment: `mysql_error()` will tell you exactly why the query failed (which is why `mysql_num_rows()` is complaining.

Comment: a few suggestions, you do not need a ";" inside the query and are you sure you are able to connect to the db at all ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698740/mysql-num-rows-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource)

Comment: So would you guys recommend using select count(*) instead of num_rows()?

Comment: @JonahAllibone: No... I'd recommend `SELECT 1...LIMIT 1` if you just want to check if something exists.

Comment: Also, where is your closing `}` on your else?

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)()

> Retrieves the number of rows from a result set. **This command is only valid for statements like SELECT or SHOW that return an actual result set.** To retrieve the number of rows affected by a INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE or DELETE query, use mysql_affected_rows().

Instead of doing `SELECT *` and then mysql_num_rows(), you can do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` and then retrieve the number of rows, by fetching the field (that should be 0 or 1). SELECT COUNT will always return a result (provided that the query syntax is correct of course).

Also, change the query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username';";
```

into

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" 
    . mysql_real_escape_string($username)  . "';";
```

Comment: `SELECT 1 ... LIMIT 1` would be quicker, no? No need to count the number of users, just need to know that one exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, have you ever heard of upserts? I.E., "insert on duplicate key". They'd be useful to you in this situation, at least if your username column is a unique key.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Never heard of it. Ill take a look

Comment: I don't think he wants to perform an update "on duplicate" though... I think `INSERT IGNORE` would be better suited for the task, no?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
```

i think you have to replace the above to

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$username]);
```

Comment: no because username is already the name a variable with $_POST content