# mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in 15

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

Every time I try to run my script I get this error, saying that  `mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource.` I'm not quite sure why its doing this. My goal is to get it to check to see if the client who logs in is an admin.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    if ($username&&$password)
    {

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    //connect
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","*******_robert","***********") or die ("Couldn't Connect"); //host,username,password
    mysql_select_db("virtua15_gateway") or die ("Could not find database");
    //query
    $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user'");
    $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($numrows!=0)
    {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
                $dbusername = $row['username'];
                $dbpassword = $row['password'];
        }
        if ($username==$dbusername&&$password==$dbpassword)
        {
         header( 'Location: index2.php' );
         $_SESSION['username']=$dbusername;
        }
        else
            echo "incorrect username and password";
    }
       else
         die ("This user does not exist");

    }
    else
        die("Please enter a username and a password");


    while($get = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))

{
 $admin = $row['admin'];
}
if ($admin==0)
 die ("You are not and admin!");
header('Location: index2.php')

?>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've already seen this kind of question... [hint: check questions under the "related" tab on the right ---->]

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698740/mysql-num-rows-supplied-argument-is-not-a-valid-mysql-result-resource)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

So, is it `$get` or `$query`?

Answer (score 3):

You call your query resource $get, but then pass it as $query. Choose one :)

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Also, add an error checking in case the query fails (die() or trigger_error())

Might be also worth noting you need to escape any input instead of feeding it directly in your query (even from $_SESSION or $_COOKIES, not only $_POST). Use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) for that. And you should not store password in clear text, might use [sha1()](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) or better hashing algos.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($get);
```

instead of :

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$user'");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($get);
```

change $query to $get